(LMVT) Minimum no. of roots of $f(x)(f'(x))^3+(f(x)^2)f'(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)=x(f'(x))^2+xf(x)f''(x)-x$ based on some given conditions
Complete Question :
Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(-1)=f(1)=1$ and $f(0)=0$.
Find the minimum number of distinct solutions to the equation:
$f(x)(f'(x))^3+(f(x)^2)f'(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)=x(f'(x))^2+xf(x)f''(x)-x$

The question involves MVT and Rolle's Theorem. I simplified the above equation to:
${[f(x)f'(x)-x]}{[f(x)f'(x)-x]'}=0$
Assuming a twice differentiable function $h(x)=f(x)f'(x)-x$, I tried to apply LMVT or Rolle's Theorem to first find minimum no. of zeroes of $h(x)$ and hence find minimum no. of roots of $h'(x)$ but I couldn't find any zeros of h(x) except for $x=0$.
Any help is appreciated.
Answer to the main question is 5.

The above simplified equation is not correct. The best I could simplify it was $$ f(x)f'(x)(f(x)f'(x)-x)'=x(f'(x)+f(x)f''(x)-1).$$
or $$ (f(x)f'(x)-x)(f(x)f'(x)-x)'=x(f'(x)-(f'(x))^2)$$

@Sam I'm sorry for the mistake in typing, I've edited the question.
